# Extracting CPU use for specific process periodically

Tags: python, regex, awk, cpu

I have a running demo on a Linux server which consumes quite a bit of CPU and Memory usage. These parameters keep changing based on the load of the running demo.  I want to extract the CPU usage and Memory usage periodically , i.e. every 3-4 sec and create a plot of the extracted result.

Considering the process as " Running Demo", on the terminal I typed:

```
ps aux |grep Running Demo | awk '{print $3 $4}'
```

This gives me the CPU and Memory usage of Running Demo. But I want the next two things i.e.
1) get this result outputted every 3-4 sec.
2) Make a plot of the generated result.

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated. I am a starter in this community.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to do is well known as an existing project :

See [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)

**EXAMPLE**

[image]

**NOTE**

- it's supported by the Open Source community, so...
- it will be stronger
- don't run odd commands like `ps aux |grep Running Demo | awk '{print $3 $4}'` but `ps auxw | awk '/Running Demo/{print $3 $4}'`
- many plugins exists and works for basics : CPU, RAM, FW, Apache and many more
- if you really need `gnuplot`, see a top 3 on a goggle search http://blah.token.ro/post/249956031/using-gnuplot-to-graph-process-cpu-usage

Comment: Just checked it out. Seems like a handy tool. I will give it a try on my local machine. Although I want to have this in gnuplot if possible.

Comment: Added gnuplot example link

Comment: with Python support obviously as the code I am working on is in python.

Answer (score 0):

the following python script accepts an output filename (png), and one or more pids. when you press ctrl-C it stops and uses gnuplot to generate a nice graph.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import tempfile
import time
import sys

def total(pids):
    return [sum(map(int, file('/proc/%s/stat' % pid).read().split()[13:17])) for pid in pids]

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) == 1 or sys.argv[1] == '-h':
        print 'log.py output.png pid1 pid2..'
        return
    pids = sys.argv[2:]
    results = []
    prev = total(pids)
    try:
        while True:
            new = total(pids)
            result = [(new[i]-prev[i])/0.1 for i, pid in enumerate(pids)]
            results.append(result)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            prev = new
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    t1, t2 = tempfile.mkstemp()[1], tempfile.mkstemp()[1]
    f1, f2 = file(t1, 'w'), file(t2, 'w')
    print
    print 'data: %s' % t1
    print 'plot: %s' % t2
    for result in results:
        print >>f1, ' '.join(map(str, result))
    print >>f2, 'set terminal png size %d,480' % (len(results)*5)
    print >>f2, "set out '%s'" % sys.argv[1]
    print >>f2, 'plot ' + ', '.join([("'%s' using ($0/10):%d with linespoints title '%s'" % (t1, i+1, pid)) for i, pid in enumerate(pids)])
    f1.close()
    f2.close()
    os.system('gnuplot %s' % t2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```